# Copying a UIButton using unarchivedObjectOfClass - object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

To copy a UIButton this works:

```
NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: btn];
UIButton *newButton = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: archivedData];
[originalBtnsArray addObject:newButton];
```

However, since iOS 12.0, the NSKeyedUnarchiver is deprecated. But when trying the below, the newButton is nil.

```
NSData *archivedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:btn requiringSecureCoding:nil error:nil];    
// unarchivedObjectOfClass shows error - couldn't be read because it isn't in correct format?
NSError *error = nil;
UIButton *newButton = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[UIButton class] fromData:archivedData error:&error];    
[originalBtnsArray addObject:newButton]; // Fails here as newButton is nil
```

Please note, (before any consideration of duplication), that the class of an object is not an array, and therefore unarchivedObjectOfClass (singular) method is desired. There is no special encoding either!

How can I use unarchivedObjectOfClass to copy a UIButton?

Thanks.

Comment: requiringSecureCoding takes in BOOL but you are giving nil. Is that OK?

Comment: Where did you get archived `UIButton`?

Comment: @Shreeram Bhat - requiringSecureCoding:NO doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Cy-4AH for (UIButton *btn in btnsReferencesArray){ - but should that matter? The deprecated code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2962884-unarchivedobjectofclass?language=objc),

> Make sure you have adopted NSSecureCoding in the types you decode. If
>   any call to a decode-prefixed method fails, the default
>   decodingFailurePolicy sets the error rather than throwing an
>   exception. In this case, the current and all subsequent decode calls
>   return 0 or nil.

For decoding to work you need to adapt secure coding by specifying **requiringSecureCoding** YES.

Comment: requiringSecureCoding:YES does not make any difference. The same error remains.